# Disabled menuItem?

Tags: java, android, menu, material-design

Kind people! Tell me how to make such an elementary thing as a disabled menu item with the appropriate appearance, as in the example from material design? Programmatically. Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

EDIT: The following examples will disable click, but do not change the appearance according to the material design:

Code example:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.someItem);
        menuItem.setEnable(false);
}
```

Xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/someItem"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="Some title" />
</menu>
```

Comment: ***Maybe*** set the [`disabled`](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/) prop ([`MenuItem`](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) inherits it)!?

Comment: I tried to use `menuItem.setEnabled(false)`;, but it doesn't change the look :(

Comment: Can you provide some code how do you inflate the menu, and get this item

Comment: Do you get the same by using the same code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` after inflating it with `inflater.inflate()`?

Comment: Likewise... the item is disabled but not faint like in the images. Apparently this is simply not provided by android, which is very strange

Comment: very shocking .. can you try on different APIs/Mobile sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround on how to change the text color in the menu item. It is extremely sad that such an elementary thing is not provided out of the box. Perhaps someone has a better solution, I'll be glad to see!

```
MenuItem  menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.some_item);
menuItem.setEnabled(false);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, s.length(), 0);
menuItem.setTitle(s);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can do Add, Remove, or Disable menu items and change text color of menu item at Runtime like that::**

> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu() callback.)
>
> On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onPrepareOptionsMenu() each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be open when menu items are presented in the app bar. When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call onPrepareOptionsMenu().

You can see [the Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/someItem"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:title="Some title"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.TextView" 
    // if using androidX
    //app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView"/>
 </menu>
```

And in java code

```
 //sample code
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
   //disable menu item and change text color
   MenuItem menu1 = menu.findItem(R.id.yourmenuid);
   menu1.setEnabled(false);
   TextView textView = (TextView) menu1.getActionView();
   textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
   return true;
  }
```

**you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call onPrepareOptionsMenu().**

Comment: It's not a problem. The problem is that the appearance of the item remains unchanged. It does not become the same as in the example material design

Comment: @ДенисВережников please check now.

Comment: I tried it for a long time. Unsuccessfully... The textview itself is found, but not displayed for some reason